# How to add Deep Linking in instagram add/post

Tags: android, deep-linking

Is there any way to add deep-linking in Instagram post/add, so that it will open the app instead of a browser (like facebook adds) if the app is installed. So far I have seen many posts on how to open Instagram from another app, but I need the reverse one.

Answer (score 0):

**Ads, yes. Posts, no.**

[Branch](http://branch.io) has a solution for this. Here's the [blogpost](https://blog.branch.io/3-quick-steps-to-deep-linking-your-instagram-install-ads/) about it. I suggest using Branch for deep linking as it will make your life much easier. Otherwise, I believe normal [App Links](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html) should accomplish this for you if you just embed them in the ad.